# Spread operator and EsLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I want to copy object and change one of its field. Something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  showTagPanel: false,
};

export default function reducerFoo(state = initialState, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case types.SHOW_TAG_PANEL:
      console.log(state);

      return {
        ...state,
        showTagPanel: true
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This code works fine, but `eslint` show me error

```
Unexpected token (14:8)
  12 |
  13 |       return {
> 14 |         ...state,
     |         ^
  15 |         showTagPanel: true
  16 |       };
  17 |
```

Here is my .eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-var": 1,
    "semi": [1, "always"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0,
    "jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/display-name": [ 1, {"ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [1, {"forbid": ["any"]}],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
    "react/no-set-state": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1
  }
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try adding `"experimentalObjectRestSpread": true` to `"ecmaFeatures"`.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## Update as of eslint 5.0.0

Source: https://eslint.org/docs/5.0.0/user-guide/migrating-to-5.0.0

Add `ecmaVersion: 2018` to `parserOptions` in your `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
    }
  }
}
```

## Original answer

Add `"experimentalObjectRestSpread": true` to `ecmaFeatures` in your `.eslintrc` file.

**Example**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And need to update eslint to the latest version.

Comment: I googled, and this was the first page that helped me. Thank you!

Comment: If it stills gives error, try adding "transform-object-rest-spread" in .babalrc file. 

{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}

Comment: `"experimentalObjectRestSpread": true` was **deprecated** in favor of `"ecmaVersion": 2018`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I still get `...calculateStatsPerFile(messages)
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)`

Comment: The problem is adding this breaks a whole lot of other rules...

Answer (score 2):

Btw, if answered from @Alexander at 15 July 2017 not solving your problem. Please change your `ecmaVersion` into `2018`, like this:

```
ESLint ^5 or newer version
{
  "env": {...},
  "extends": [...],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018, // use this.
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // just use this on ecmaFeatures, no need "experimentalObjectRestSpread" anymore.
    }
  }
}
```

instead using `"experimentalObjectRestSpread": true` like this:

```
This is only for ESLint under v5
{
  "env": {...},
  "extends": [...],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true // instead this
    }
  }
}
```

For complete explanation about this, you can read here -> [`experimentalObjectRestSpread` has been DEPRECATED](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-5.0.0#experimental-object-rest-spread).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I still get `...calculateStatsPerFile(messages)
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)`

Comment: @Ryan How about another "rules"? Is it worked or not on your project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Yes, I do have a block of `rules` in my `.eslintrc.js` file too.